# translating php sha1 to c#

Tags: c#, php, .net

What is `self::prefix`? How this line will looks like in C#?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `self` should be equivalent to `this`, but what is `prefix` and what do the `$this` do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just find static member called prefix in your class and replace it in C# with that value. It's a simple variable.